# Trying to plot background color for intraday margin rates

Tags: pine-script

Trying to plot a selected background color for reminding myself while I'm trading of when intraday margin rates begin and end. I copied this from another indicator and fiddled with it, though I didn't change very much at all. Keep getting "undeclared identifier" errors. Can't understand what I'm doing wrong. Errors:

```
Error: Undeclared identifier `input.string`;
Error: Undeclared identifier `input.string`;
Error: Undeclared identifier `begin0`;
Error: Undeclared identifier `end0`;
Error: Undeclared identifier `sess0`;
Error: Undeclared identifier `bgPlot0`
```

Code:

```
study(title="Highlight/Display/Show intraday trading session/period", shorttitle="intraday", overlay=true)
use0 = input(true, title="Highlight intraday trading session")
begin0 = input(title="Begin", type=input.string, defval="0800")
end0 = input(title="End", type=input.string, defval="1500")
sess0 = begin0 + "-" + end0
bgPlot0 = time(period, sess0)
bgcolor(use0 and bgPlot0 > 0 ? black : na, transp=98)
```

Comment: I'm an idiot noob. Forgot the version statement. Works a little better now. Only getting two errors.

```line 7: Undeclared identifier 'period';
line 8: Undeclared identifier 'bgPlot0'```

Comment: Fixed it. it's working now. `period` has to be `timeframe.period`

Comment: It's actually showing one hour prior for both begin and end. Is that because futures are central time? (I'm eastern.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mixed v3 and v4 syntax:

```
//@version=4
study(title="Highlight/Display/Show intraday trading session/period", shorttitle="intraday", overlay=true)
use0 = input(true, title="Highlight intraday trading session")
begin0 = input(title="Begin", type=input.string, defval="0800")
end0 = input(title="End", type=input.string, defval="1500")
sess0 = begin0 + "-" + end0
bgPlot0 = time(timeframe.period, sess0)
bgcolor(use0 and bgPlot0 > 0 ? color.black : na, transp=98)
```

These are the v4 docs:

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/Introduction.html

Comment: Sorry. I didn't refresh before I commented above. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I actually fixed the color variable along with the period variable. Any idea why it's showing an hour prior? If it's set for 0800-1500, it actually shows 0900-1600.

Comment: 1. Your chart's time needs to be set to the exchange's time.

2. If you don't have extended hours and the normal session begins after 0800, you'll only see bars for normal sessions.